# javax.naming.NameNotFoundException for migrating from IBM Mq to tomcat

Tags: jms, ibm-mq, tomcat8

I am receiving below exception while trying to connect JMS MQ using tomcat. We are migrating from WebSphere to Tomcat.So currently I am using IBM MQ jars

```
2018-11-21 12:26:53,862 DEBUG com.mbfs.slr.bo.pe.JMSClient.sendMsg:283 - Exception occured : null
2018-11-21 12:26:53,863 DEBUG com.mbfs.slr.bo.pe.JMSClient.receiveMessage:384 - Trying to receive message ...
2018-11-21 12:26:53,863 DEBUG com.mbfs.slr.bo.pe.JMSClient.receiveMessage:385 - getJndiConnectionFactory : jms/Name of Queue
2018-11-21 12:26:53,863 DEBUG com.mbfs.slr.bo.pe.JMSClient.receiveMessage:386 - getRecieveJndiQueueName : jms/name of receiving queue
2018-11-21 12:26:53,864 DEBUG com.mbfs.slr.bo.pe.JMSClient.createQueue:221 - Created JNDI intial Context ...
2018-11-21 12:26:53,864 DEBUG com.mbfs.slr.bo.pe.JMSClient.createQueue:239 - JNDI API lookup failed: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jms/NAmeofQueue] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jms].
```

I have placed all IBM MQ jars.I have placed entry in TomEE server.xml and web.xml.
Please let me know if I am missing any configuration

I have placed following entry in
Server.xml

```
<Resource name="jms/XXXBQueueConnectionFactory" auth="Container" type="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory" factory="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactoryFactory" description="JMS Queue Connection Factory" HOST="XXXX" PORT="XX5" CHAN="XXX" TRAN="1" QMGR="XXX" />
```

Comment: What version of MQ are the jars from and what jars did you include.  Can you show server.xml and web.xml entries too?  All of this should be added to your question by selecting edit.

Comment: Server.xml entry : <Resource name="jms/XXXBQueueConnectionFactory" auth="Container"
            type="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory" factory="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactoryFactory"
            description="JMS Queue Connection Factory"
            HOST="XXXX" PORT="XX5" CHAN="XXX" TRAN="1"
            QMGR="XXX" />

Comment: web.xml <resource-ref>
    <description>MQ</description>
    <res-ref-name>jms/XXXXXQueueConnectionFactory</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
  </resource-ref>

Comment: I have added com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.1.0.0 jar under tomcat

Comment: Sorry but after editing when I click on save few information is being lost.Hence added as comment

Comment: Following jars I have included under Tomcat lib
1.ProviderUtil.jar
2.jms.jar
3.com.ibm.mq
4.com.ibm.mq.headers
5.com.ibm.mq.commonservices
6.com.ibm.dhbcore
7.com.ibm.mq.jmqi
8.com.ibm.mqjms
9.com.ibm.mq.osgi.directip_7.0.1.3
10.com.ibm.mq.pcf
11.connector
12.jms-4.4
13.fscontext-1.2.1
14.jndi-1.2.1

Comment: Any input would be appreciated please.JoshMc?

Comment: When you click edit mode you can see how i fixed it,  please add the rest,  anything proceeded by 4 spaces will format as code.

Comment: Once you put the information in the question i'l see what i can do to help.  You mentioned allclient 9.1.0.0 but then list a number of other jars,  are those from the same version of mq? You can check the manifest in each jar for the version.

Comment: Since tomcat uses JMS, you have to setup a `.bindings` file to bind the jms name to an MQ object.  The MQ explorer console has a seciton for that.